# Why do I need a return to get back to system prompt?

Tags: shell, unix, posix, tee

I have been trying to write POSIX compliant code and would like to get `stdout` and `stderr` to a log file as well as to the screen using [tee](/questions/tagged/tee).

The program runs ok and does what it is supposed to ..
but the system prompt does not appear until i hit carriage return (again).
I am not sure why this is happening.
Does anyone know how I can avoid this happening?

```
rm mylog.txt
exec > >(tee -a mylog.txt)
exec 2>&1
echo food
echo bar
exit
```

Comment: POSIX code with process substitution? When did they add that?

Comment: Besides being non-POSIX, the process substitution is probably the cause of your problem. It's a little flaky. It's probably exiting the shell without waiting for the `tee` process to exit first, causing the prompt to be overwritten by the last bit of output from tee

Answer (score 0):

Never saw your syntax with this `exec >` thing... so I cannot explain what you get (I'm not getting the same as you say - this might be specific to the shell you're using).

You could **avoid to have this behavior** by doing a wrapper around your script; here is how to:

```
#!/bin/bash
# removing even when non existing
rm -f  mylog.txt
{
  echo food
  echo bar
  # testing the stderr too:
  ls -la non_existant_file
} 2>&1 | tee -a  mylog.txt
```

Comment: I don't think this explains what another_bug is seeing, at all.

Comment: Just trying to help... It would help to use a hammer instead of a screwdriver to nail.

Comment: Thanks you have all helped me to understand a little about where I am messing this up (a lot). I will make the suggested changes.